# problem with the NFA to DFA conversion theorem

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, finite-automata

I have been given the following NFA:

[image: NFA]

and, using the conversion algorithm (creating a new event for every union of events), I came up with the following DFA (note: I added here the events from the NFA, even if they are never accessed, for clarity on how the union events are formed):

[image: NFA]

However, I can clearly see that something is wrong: the NFA rejects the string "ababa", yet my DFA accepts it. The transition $\delta^*(\{A,C,D\},a)$ returns the event $\{A,B,D\}$, an accepting state. Through sheer intuition, I imagine it should instead return the event $\{A,B\}$, but I don't quite see what went wrong. I've redone this multiple times, each time with the same result. What I am doing wrong in my application of the theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NFA accepts the string "ababa":

A -> A -> A -> B -> C -> D

Remember that an NFA accepts if there is *some* path which leads to an accepting state.

Comment: wow, I can't believe I didn't see that. Good catch, thanks for the help.